# Using @extend in Webpack

Tags: webpack, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm using the bootstrap node package in my webpack setup, and importing it with my other modules at my entry point `app.js` like so:

```
import 'bootstrap';
import 'font-awesome-loader';
import './assets/scss/app.scss';
console.log('Its working just fine!');
```

My `./assets/scss/app.scss` file imports other `.scss` files, and within those files I'm using `@extend` to extend the bootstrap `.container` class:

```
 .banner {

  @extend .container;

  &__logo-holder {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 2rem 0;
  }

  // and so on ...
}
```

I get the following error on compilation:

```
@extend .container;
         ^
      ".banner" failed to @extend ".container".
The selector ".container" was not found.
```

Is the use of @extend even possible when using Webpack? I took it for granted using gulp.

Comment: I think gulp-sass includes each file's source in the `data` option that is passed to sass, making everything globally accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import bootstrap directly in `./assets/scss/app.scss`